# How to concanenate an incremental id to an existing value

Tags: xslt

I have the following xml:

[image]

I would like to concatenate the postioName column an incremental ID, for example:

[image]

So far I have managed to achieve something similar using the function : "generate-id()" but the result in not quite what I expect:

[image]

Is there a better way to achieve this?

The way I am doing it is:

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <!-- Identity transform -->
 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="/IDS/records/positionName">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:value-of select="../positionName"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="'_'"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```html
<IDS>
 <records>
  <positionId>a</positionId>
  <positionName>ID</positionName>
  <maturityDate>20251217</maturityDate>
 </records>
 <records>
  <positionId>b</positionId>
  <positionName>ID</positionName>
  <maturityDate>20251217</maturityDate>
 </records>
 <records>
  <positionId>c</positionId>
  <positionName>ID</positionName>
  <maturityDate>20251217</maturityDate>
 </records>
</IDS>
```

Comment: Note that XSLT 3 allows you to avoid spelling out the identity transform as you have done by simply declaring `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` instead.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use `<xsl:number count="records"/>` to generate the number, `<xsl:value-of select=". || '_'"/><xsl:number count="records"/>`, so a complete XSLT 3 stylesheet is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="/IDS/records/positionName">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select=". || '_'"/>
        <xsl:number count="records"/> 
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7m5/1